# Expected expression before char in C

Tags: c, function-call

[image][image]I am doing a word search program and keep getting the same error that doesn't give me much information about whats wrong. Specifically it says this...

```
wordSearch.c:38:32: error: expected
  expression
```

returnWord = (char *) strstr(char const *sentence, char const *phrase);
                               ^
                                                     ^
what could this be?

Comment: If `returnWord` is char* then you need to cast as `(char*)`

Comment: @Riad why the cast is needed?

Comment: Don't know about returnWord variable. If it is string then can be used directly. But he is writing as char * without parenthesis... May this causing error.

Comment: @Riad This is not C++. 1) there is no `string` type, 2) the syntax is wrong, as OP used the type in other places also in the  call, which shows OP has got the function call syntax wrong.

Comment: added the parenthesis to (char*)

Comment: do NOT post images, rather, select the text, then copy/paste into the question, indented by 4 spaces.  Generally, to help you, we need to be able to copy/paste your code into our editor then compile it

Comment: regarding the loop:  `while( token != NULL )`   The variable `token` has not been initialized (your compiler should have told you about this problem.) so your program has undefined behavior.  Suggest call `strtok()` once before the loop and again at the end of the loop

Comment: OT: regarding: `sentence = malloc( 100 );`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "malloc failed" );` so both the `malloc failed` and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `fgets( sentence, 99, stdin)`  The function `fgets()` properly honors the length of the receiving buffer,  so `99` is wasting a byte.  Also, the code contains the 'magic' numbers 99 and 100.  'magic' numbers make the code more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` statements or an `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: regarding: `returnword = (char*) strstr(...)`  The function: `strstr()` returns a `char*` so the cast just clutters the code and is not needed

Comment: the posted code contains a memory leak.  It calls `malloc()` and assigns the resulting pointer to `sentence`, but fails to call `free( sentence );` before exiting the program

Comment: regarding: `token = strtok( NULL, " " );`   The first time (for each new string) the name of the string (I.E. a pointer to the string) must be used, rather than NULL.  Thereafter, for each subsequent operation on the same string, the first parameter must be NULL.

Comment: regarding the code block, beginning with: `while( token != NULL )`  what happens if there are more than 10 sub strings/words in the user input?   Strongly suggest using `while( i<10 && token != NULL )`

Comment: when calling `fgets()` always check the returned value because the user can do several things to 'messup' the operation, like entering EOF

Comment: regarding: `fgets( phrase, 99, stdin )`   This can (and probably will) result in a seg fault event because the pointer `phrase` has never been set to point to any memory that the program owns

Answer (score 3):

`returnWord = char *strstr(const char *sentence, const char *phrase);`

is not how you call a function. Get rid of the return type, simply use

```
returnWord = strstr(sentence, phrase);
```

assuming `sentence` and `phrase` are variables are defined and having proper values.

Comment: when trying this I got segmentation fault 11

Comment: @ Sourav Ghosh is correct to point out the obvious syntax error  and if your having segmentation fault I would suggest you to check values of sentence and phrase variables before passing them to strstr() function. If they are empty simply return from the  wordSearch function. Even after that it is not resoved you need to compile it again with "-g"  flag and run it on GDB.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pictures, it looks as if something is wrong with `strstr`. This makes sense because of the way you are passing arguments. `strstr` expects two `const char *` arguments, however you have casted them incorrectly. Additionally, since `strstr` already returns a `char *` there is no need to cast that. Thus, line 38 should be `returnword = strstr((const char *) sentence, (const char *) phrase);`

Comment: Include the wordsearch.c program in the original post

Comment: ah okay, i added a picture